# Relative positioning of node in tikzpicture depending on condition

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, conditionals

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, ellipse}]
    \node[main] (0) {0};
    \node[main, below=10mm of 0] (1) {1};
    \node[main, below=10mm of 1] (2) {2};
    \node[main, right=10mm of 1] (3) {3};
    \node[main,\ifthenelse{1>0}{above}{below}=10mm of 3] (4) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to place node 4 either above or below of node 3, depending on a condition. How do I achieve this? So far, I only get the following error message:

> Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }. ...\ifthenelse{1>0}{above}{below}=10mm of 3]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where is defined condition?

Comment: It's the ifthenelse in line 6, for this example it's just 1>0?

Comment: For example `\ifthenelse{1>0}{\node[main,above=10mm of 3] (4) {4};}{\node[main,below=10mm of 3] (4) {4};}`

Comment: You not understand me, I see your c`\ifthanelse`, but `1 ` is always greater than `0`. What sense has such condition? There is still something missing. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by `IfValueTF` key from tcolorbox, you could create something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\tikzset{
  ifthen/.code n args={3}{
    \ifthenelse{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, ellipse}]
    \node[main] (0) {0};
    \node[main, below=10mm of 0] (1) {1};
    \node[main, below=10mm of 1] (2) {2};
    \node[main, right=10mm of 1] (3) {3};
    \node[
      main,
      ifthen={1<0}{above=10mm of 3}{below=10mm of 3}
    ] (4) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excellent answer! +1, but in positioning I would use `node distance` (set to 10mm) .

Answer (score 1):

This example works. (with package `ifthen`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{ifthen} 

\begin{document}        
    
    \textbf{\#4 above \#3}\medskip
    \newcommand{\z}{0}      
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, ellipse}]
        \node[main] (0) {0};
        \node[main, below=10mm of 0] (1) {1};
        \node[main, below=10mm of 1] (2) {2};
        \node[main, right=10mm of 1] (3) {3};
        \ifthenelse{1>\z}{\node[main,above=10mm of 3] (4) {4};}{\node[main,below=10mm of 3] (4) {4};}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \bigskip        
    
    \textbf{\#4 below \#3}\medskip      
    \renewcommand{\z}{2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={20mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, ellipse}]
    \node[main] (0) {0};
    \node[main, below=10mm of 0] (1) {1};
    \node[main, below=10mm of 1] (2) {2};
    \node[main, right=10mm of 1] (3) {3};
    \ifthenelse{1>\z}{\node[main,above=10mm of 3] (4) {4};}{\node[main,below=10mm of 3] (4) {4};}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Where you find `\z` option? In OP question is not provided (see my comments there). In contrary to OP question your suggestion has some sense ...

Comment: @Zarko The OP shows a simplified MWE

Comment: @Zarko  It is not an "option". It is a command I defined to test both branches.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, OP code fragment is to simplified. So, condition in it has not sense. However, answer added information, when question has some sense :-)

Comment: @Zarko It has sense, it will always force the `false` branch.

Comment: Well, If all say so ...